# How to configure path for file download in python-selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, test-automation-framework, chromedriver

I have changed the path of file download from using below code.

```
chromeOptions=Options()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory":  r"C:\Users\Ads\downloadfolder", "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
```

I have developed 29 different scripts to download different documents from different web applications.
I have put above code in all the scripts but I want to define it at one place and use across all the scripts. It will help me to change the download path at once if required instead of changing it by editing all the scripts.

Comment: i guess, create a method that returns chrome option :

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=setup.GetOptions())

Comment: I tried using new python file and call it in script file but its downloading to download file which is default of chrome and not to my defined file.

Comment: add what you have tried and failed

Comment: I have created one python file using above code.                     
chromeOptions=Options()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory":  r"C:\Users\Ads\downloadfolder", "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)     and then called it in my script as  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeOptions=Options())

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeOptions=Options()) it doesn't have any connection to python file you created , you are still creating new Options()

Comment: Ya and it is setting my download path.

Comment: What change should I make?

Comment: if you created `chromeOptions=...` in one file then in another you should use this variable `Chrome(chromeOptions=chromeOptions)` if you made `from onefile import chromeOptions`. `Chrome(chromeOptions=onefile.chromeOptions)` if you made `iport onefile` BUT if you in one file created even `driver = ...` then you don't have to create it again in another file. But I would rather create function `get_options()` or `create_drive()` in one file to use it `driver = Chrome(chromeOptions=onefile.get_options())` or `driver = onefile.create_driver()`

Comment: I tried as mentioned but its opening chrome twice every time and application is opening in one where download path is default as downloads. Well, another query here is, how to get the path from excel to set in download.default_directory?

Comment: @Amaze_Rock add simple project and code structure to your question , else it's hard to understand who u are calling this python files

Answer (score 1):

Create a file say Setup.py in package say common:

with below content

```
def getOptions():
    chromeOptions=Options()
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory":  r"C:\Users\Ads\downloadfolder", "download.prompt_for_download": False, "download.directory_upgrade": True   "safebrowsing.enabled": True})
    return chromeOptions
```

And when ever you are creating driver in the test scripts add below import:

```
from common import Setup
```

and now call option in the test script as

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Setup.getOptions())
```